# Passing a string to pthread function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm a beginner to pthreads so bear with me. I'm trying to pass a string to the `thread_routine1` function. It takes a void pointer as an argument. I then want to print it out.

```
void *thread_routine1(void *arg1){
    cout << arg1 << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    string t1 = "hello", t2 = "world";
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,thread_routine1, (void *) t1);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

In the pthread_creat function I'm attempting to pass the string but I'm getting a invalid cast type from string to void pointer. I understand I'm probably goin wrong in more than one place so I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Although you should be using `std::thread`, as noted, if your intent is to actually write C++ code, in the event you have some specific reason to be using posix threads: you cannot convert a class instance to a `void *`, but you can convert a pointer to anything into a `void *`, so all you have to do is use the address-of operator to obtain a pointer to your `std::string`, then convert that to a `void *`. Having said that, you will eventually discover that using `std::cout` to display a `void *` will not give you useful results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pthreads, really. You do this cast `(void *) t1`, which is essentially taking a sledgehammer onto the type system.

A string in C++ is not a pointer, so casting it to - and treating it as - one is only going to cause undefined behavior.

This is one reason why a C-style cast is to be avoided, because had you done it with a `static_cast<void*>(t1)` you'd have gotten a proper error, scolding you for doing something you shouldn't be doing.

Now, if you can't use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for all its abstractions, and must contend with the pthreads C API, the way to go is to pass the *address* of `t1`. I.e.

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,thread_routine1, &t1);
```

And now you don't even need a cast, because you are working *with* the type system. An object pointer is implicitly convertible to `void*`. Well-designed code should not be peppered with casts. They should be infrequent and for a good reason only. Furthermore, a cast should *never* be written just to "make it compile".

Oh, and don't forget to cast back in your thread function. Now you have a good reason, and the code will be correct with a simple static cast:

```
void *thread_routine1(void *arg1){
    cout << *static_cast<string*>(arg1) << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return nullptr; // The function's return type is `void*`, not `void`! Do not omit a return statement.
}
```